What's the definition of stochastic integral process at time zero? Is it always zero?
Question
Let $(M_t)$ be a continuous local martingale and let $(H_t)$ be a predictable process such that $\int_0^t H_s^2d[M]_s<\infty$ for all $0\leq t\leq \infty$.
Let $I_t$ be the process defined by the stochastic integral $I_t:=(H\cdot M)_t$.
Then, what is the definition of $I_0$ at time zero? Is it true that $I_0$ is always zero?
What I think
In the book of Rojas and Williams (IV.25.2, vol.2), the definition of $I_t$ for elementary predictable process is:
$$I_t=(H\cdot M)(t)=\sum Z_i\{M(T_i\wedge t)-M(T_{i-1}\wedge t)\}$$
where $0\leq T_1\leq ...\leq T_n$ are sequence of stopping times and $Z_i$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{T_i}$-measurable random variable.
So let $t=0$, we have $I_0=\sum Z_i\{M(0)-M(0)\} \equiv 0$.
For general (non-elementary) process $H$, we define the integral $H\cdot M$ by a sequence of elementary processes $H_n$:
$$(H\cdot M) := \lim_{n} (H_n\cdot M)$$
Since for each $n$, $(H_n\cdot M)_0=0$, we have $(H\cdot M)_0=0$.
Is this correct? If it is true, then all process defined by stochastic integral have zero at $t=0$?
Background
I am reading a material related to the integral process $(I_t)$, where the author claimed  that

If $I$ is a martinagale, then $E[I_t]=E[I_0]=0 \,\, \text{since} \,\, I_0=0 \,\, \text{by definition}$.

and I want to understand why $I_0=0$ by definition.
